# How to plot `y=y[x]` from `f[x_,y_]=f0`

Tags: plotting, inverse

Given a two-variable function

```
f[x_,y_]:=(*complicated stuff in terms of x and y *)
```

what I want is to do is `Plot` `y=y[x]` given a fixed value of `f=f0`

Comment: Use `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @Szabolcs it worked, thanks.